# WCF Remote MSMQ - I can write to a remote queue, but cannot receive

Tags: wcf, msmq

jobsServer: Windows Server 2008 R2
.NET Version: 4.5

I'm using WCF to connect two servers - **app** and **queue**. I want **app** to be able to send/receive messages from **queue**. For some reason, app can send messages, but CANNOT receive them.

The netMsmq binding looks like:

```
<binding name="JobExecutionerBinding" receiveErrorHandling="Move">
  <security>
    <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="None" msmqProtectionLevel="None" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

And the service binding looks like:

Now, the client binding looks like:

```
<endpoint   address="net.msmq://queue/private/jobs" 
            binding="netMsmqBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="JobExecutionerBinding" 
            contract="JobExecution.Common.IJobExecutionService" 
            name="SimpleEmailService" 
            kind="" 
            endpointConfiguration=""/>
```

I changed a few names for security's sake.

So, the WC client can send to the remote queue without a problem. It even properly queues the outgoing message and forwards it on later in the event that the remote queue server is down. But every time I start up the WCF service, I get this:

> There was an error opening the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is installed
>   and running, the queue exists and has proper authorization to be read
>   from. The inner exception may contain additional information. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.MsmqException: An error occurred while opening the
>   queue:The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient
>   permissions to perform the operation. (-1072824317, 0xc00e0003). The 
>   message cannot be sent or received from the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is
>   installed and running. Also ensure that the queue is available to open
>   with the required access mode and authorization.   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqQueue.OpenQueue()   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqQueue.GetHandle()   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqQueue.SupportsAccessMode(String
>   formatName, Int32 accessType, MsmqException& msmqException)   --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqVerifier.VerifyReceiver(MsmqReceiveParameters
>   receiveParameters, Uri listenUri)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqTransportBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext
>   context)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](Uri
>   listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode
>   listenUriMode, BindingParameterCollection parameters)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.MaybeCreateListener(Boolean
>   actuallyCreate, Type[] supportedChannels, Binding binding,
>   BindingParameterCollection parameters, Uri listenUriBaseAddress,
>   String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode,
>   ServiceThrottle throttle, IChannelListener& result, Boolean
>   supportContextSession)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildChannelListener(StuffPerListenUriInfo
>   stuff, ServiceHostBase serviceHost, Uri listenUri, ListenUriMode
>   listenUriMode, Boolean supportContextSession, IChannelListener&
>   result)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription
>   description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()   at

I've been all over StackOverflow and the internet for 8 hours. Here's what I've done:

- Ensured that ANONYMOUS LOGIN, Everyone, Network, Network Service, and Local Service have full control
- Stopped the remote MSMQ server and observed what the WCF service does, and I get a different error - so I'm sure that the WCF service when starting up is speaking to the MSMQ server
- Disabled Windows Firewall on both boxes and opened all ports via EC2 security groups
- Set AllowNonauthenticatedRpc and NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient to 1 in the registry
- Configured MS DTC on both servers (the queue is transactional, but I get the same error regardless as to whether the queue is transactional or not)
- Confirmed that the WCF server starts up fine if I use the local queue, and receives without a problem

Help!!! I can't scale my app without a remote queueing solution.

Comment: I get this error when use server name. When use ip I don't get an error but I don't success to read from remote private queue.

Comment: I have this same problem, with a similar config, but I am not reaching out over the network. "app" can write to the queue (which is local) but cannot receive from it (even though it is local.) I don't believe that the network connectivity itself has anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from  your post *which tier can not read* and more importantly *which queue*.

However, reading remote queues transactionally is not supported:

> *Message Queuing supports **sending** transactional messages to remote queues, **but does not support reading messages from a remote queue within a transaction**. This means that reliable, exactly-once reception is not available from remote queues.* See
>   [Reading Messages from Remote Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms699854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I suspect that somewhere your system is still performing transactional remote reads even though you mentioned you disabled it.

From a best practice point of view, even if you got it to work, your design will not scale which is a shame as it is something you mentioned you wanted.

> *Remote reading is a high-overhead and therefore inefficient process. Including remote read operations in an application limits scaling.* [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms699854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You should always *remote write* **not** remote read.

A better way is to insert a [message broker](http://www.eaipatterns.com/ramblings/03_hubandspoke.html) or *router service* that acts as the central point for messaging.  Your **app** and **queue** services (confusing names by the way) should merely *read transactionally from their local queues*.

i.e.

- **app** should transactionally read it's **local queue**
- **app** should transactionally send to the remote **broker**
- **broker** transactionally reads local queue
- **broker** transactionally sends to remote **queue**

Similarly if your **queue** tier wanted to reply the reverse process to the above would occur.

Later if you wish to improve performance you can introduce a [Dynamic router](http://www.eaipatterns.com/DynamicRouter.html) which redirects a message to a different remote queue on another machine based on dynamic rulesets or environmental conditions such as stress levels.

Answer (score 0):

Remote transactional reads are supported as of MSMQ 4.0 (Windows server 2008). If you are facing this issue, be sure to checkout https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700128(v=vs.85).aspx